# LocalStack TestContainer unable to match logs using WaitForLog

Tags: testcontainers, localstack, junit-jupiter

I'm trying to start a localstack container, this container launches a script at startup to initialize an S3 bucket, a SQS queue and a DynamoDB Table with a GSI.

Here I'm using a waitStrategy  `Wait.forLogMessage`

But the regex never catches the message so the startup fails.

Here my container:

```
@Container
static LocalStackContainer localStack =
        new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack"))
                .withFileSystemBind("src/test/resources/localstack/sqs_bootstrap.sh",
                        "/etc/localstack/init/ready.d/sqs_bootstrap.sh")
                .withServices(SQS, S3, DYNAMODB)
                .withEnv("DEBUG", "1")
                //.withLogConsumer((log) -> System.out.println(log.getUtf8String()))
                .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
                .waitingFor(
                        Wait.forLogMessage("localStack Ready to accept connections", 3)
                );
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "start localstack configuration."

set -euo pipefail

# enable debug
# set -x


echo "==================="
LOCALSTACK_HOST=localhost
AWS_REGION=eu-west-1

create_queue() {
    local QUEUE_NAME_TO_CREATE=$1
    awslocal sqs create-queue --queue-name ${QUEUE_NAME_TO_CREATE}
}

create_s3(){
    local BUCKET_NAME_TO_CREATE=$1
    awslocal s3api create-bucket --bucket ${BUCKET_NAME_TO_CREATE}
}

create_table(){
  local TABLE_NAME=$1
  local PARTITION_KEY=$2
  local PARTITION_KEY_TYPE=$3

  awslocal dynamodb create-table --table-name ${TABLE_NAME} --key-schema AttributeName=${PARTITION_KEY},KeyType=HASH \
    --attribute-definitions AttributeName=${PARTITION_KEY},AttributeType=${PARTITION_KEY_TYPE} \
    --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1

    # Add the global secondary index to the table
    awslocal dynamodb update-table --table-name ${TABLE_NAME} \
    --attribute-definitions AttributeName=searchKey,AttributeType=S \
    --global-secondary-index-updates '[{ "Create": { "IndexName": "searchIndex", "KeySchema": [{ "AttributeName": "searchKey", "KeyType": "HASH" }], "Projection": { "ProjectionType": "ALL" }, "ProvisionedThroughput": { "ReadCapacityUnits": 1, "WriteCapacityUnits": 1 } } }]'
}

echo "configuring sqs"
create_queue "oagQueue"

echo "configuring s3"
create_s3 "pss"

echo "configuring flightSchedule Table"
create_table "ps_oag" "pk" "S"

echo "localStack Ready to accept connections"
```

I've tried different patterns, but nothing works.
I also tried a healthCheck Strategy, my container startups correctly, but then my test fails cause the test under code tries to connect to the localstack container during the script execution.

Any help appreciated.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try using `.*localStack Ready to accept connections.*\\n`? I assume that method is looking for a specific pattern when it parses that String. Shortly breaking it down, we have:

- `.*`: matches any characters.
- `localstack Ready to accept connections`: matches the specific string "localstack Ready to accept connections".
- `.*\\n`: matches any characters followed by a newline.

Here are the docs where they have an example: https://java.testcontainers.org/features/startup_and_waits/

Comment: this is a pattern i already tried

    
waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(".*localStack Ready to accept connections.*\\n", 3));


but the result is the same, my test fails, the line is not match so the container startup ends in timeout

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem,
This was a mixed issue : of course the pattern you gave works perfectly.
The main issue was

```
 Wait.forLogMessage("localStack Ready to accept connections", 3)
```

the number 3, changing it to 1 makes the job works. This is the number of time you expect to see the log appearing.

So the correct answer is :

```
Wait.forLogMessage("localStack Ready to accept connections", 1)
```

Thank you so much for your time